# class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `KamdemSectionTabs`

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

My Code look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import Face from "@material-ui/icons/Face";
import Chat from "@material-ui/icons/Chat";
import Build from "@material-ui/icons/Build";

import KamdemGridContainer from "../Grid/KamdemGridContainer.js";
import KamdemGridItem from "../GridItem/KamdemGridItem.js";
import KamdemTabs from "../Tabs/KamdemTabs.js";
import TabsStyle from "./KamdemSectionTabsStyle.js";

const useStyles = makeStyles(TabsStyle);

function KamdemSectionTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
     <div className={classes.section}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div id="nav-tabs">
          <h3>Navigation Tabs</h3>
          <KamdemGridContainer>
            <KamdemGridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
              <h3><small>Tabs with Icons on Card</small></h3>
              <KamdemTabs
                headerColor="primary"
                tabs={[
                  {
                    tabName: "Profile",
                    tabIcon: Face,
                    tabContent: (
                      <p className={classes.textCenter}>text </p>
                    )
                  }
                ]}
              />
            </KamdemGridItem>
          </KamdemGridContainer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default KamdemSectionTabs;
```

Comment: Which line in your code does the error point to?

Comment: Hi, i updated my KamdemSectionTabs component

Comment: Please also share the definition of  `KamdemTabs`.